# Having trouble with returning HTTP response via Service to ViewModel (UWP MVVM)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp

I have an interface that is defined as follows:

```
internal interface IHttpService
{
    Task SendGetRequest(string param);
}
```

And the following concrete class (obviously there is compilation errors):

```
public class HttpService : IHttpService
{
    private readonly HttpClient client;
    private const string httpLink = "https://somesite.org/search?q=";
    private const string httpSuffix = "&format=json&ads=1";

    public HttpService()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "myapp");
    }

    public async Task SendGetRequest(string param)
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(httpLink + param + httpSuffix);
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

So I obviously get a compilation error when returning the ReadAsStringAsync function, but I want my viewmodel to get the response from this function. My viewmodel is as follows:

```
    public SearchViewModel()
    {
        httpService = (App.Current as App).Container.GetService<IHttpService>();

        SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            // Will need to do some proper validation here at some point
            var response = await httpService.SendGetRequest(httpStringToSend);
        });
    }
```

I'm sure i'm missing something but i'm not entirely sure what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReadAsStringAsync` is asynchronous and needs to be awaited.

You also need to use the generic `Task<T>` as your return type rather than `Task`, because your asynchronous operation is returning a value i.e. `string`.

```
public async Task<string> SendGetRequest(string param)
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(httpLink + param + httpSuffix);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

`HttpResponseMessage` is also `IDisposable` so you should add a `using` block:

```
public async Task<string> SendGetRequest(string param)
{
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(httpLink + param + httpSuffix))
    {
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still got a complication error, but i changed the return type to "Task<string>". That works "i think"...

Comment: Thanks for the edit Johnathan, stupid error that I didn't see :\ thank you :)